# Drawing numbers without replacement until you get your desired number.

Tags: probability

If you have a bag of numbers $1-10$, and you draw (without replacement) until you get the number $1$, what is the probability that you get $1$ on the $i^\text{th}$ try?

I tried to approach this problem with: $P(i=1) = 1/10, P(i=2) = (9/10)(1/9), P(i=3) = (9/10)(8/9)(1/8)...,$ but this gave me $(1/10)$ for each $i$ value, which I am pretty sure is incorrect. How else should should I approach this problem?

Comment: Indeed, $\frac 1{10}$ is correct.  Assuming you are drawing randomly, the special number is no more or less  likely to be in one position than another.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am confused about the sample space. There is only one way to pick the correct number first, and more than one way to pick the correct number on the ith time, so wouldn't the probability of picking the correct number on the first try be less than the others? But also I understand that the probability of picking the correct number on the first try is 1/10, I'm just a bit confused about the sample space.

Comment: Perhaps the most enlightening way to picture a sample space for this problem is to imagine that you draw all $10$ numbers regardless of when you happen to get your favorite number, keeping track of the draws.  Then there are $10!$ elements of your sample space.  Of these, exactly $9!$ have your favorite number in a given slot, so the desired probability is $\frac {9!}{10!}=\frac 1{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

"There is only one way to pick the correct number first."  No.  You're not considering all the variations in subsequent number selections.

There are many ways to approach this classic problem to see the answer is $1/10$.  I prefer ones based on the logic of interchange symmetry:

Let the probability of choosing a $1$ on the first selection be $p$.  Can you see that the probability of choosing a $2$ on the first selection must *also* be $p$?  (How could it be different?)  And likewise for all $10$ numbers.  But *SOME* number will be chosen first, so the sum of all the $p$s must equal $1$.

QED.